# Product Stock List using SOAP API

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, soap-api-v1

I am using following code to get the stock detail I am getting product stock of `productId` 149428

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://yourstore.com/api/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiuser', 'apiKey');
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list','149428');
var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { ["product_id"]=> string(6) "149428" ["sku"]=> string(13) "n12345" ["qty"]=> string(6) "1.0000" ["is_in_stock"]=> string(1) "1" } }
```

But I want to retrieve all products stock list instead of getting single product stock details.

I tried using  the below method but I am not getting a result,

```
$result = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list');
var_dump($result);
```

Another:

```
$result = $client->call($session, 'cataloginventory_stock_item.list');
var_dump($result);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What happens, if you try the other two?

Comment: it displays result as array(0) { }

Comment: @fabian is there any solutions for that please do help me

Comment: Reading the docs brings me to the assumption, that you have to implement your own API if you want "all", but you can pass an array with "all" ids, then you get all. You can read the code of the api response (don't ask me, what class handles that - no idea) and check, whether me/doc is wrong.

Comment: @Fabian I tried sending ids in array but it did not work. as its reading first id from array and skipping the rest all

Answer (score 0):

You can use magento api version 2 for getting different product stocks in a single call. Try below code:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magento-local.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl'); //Means you are calling magento api V2
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test', 'test123'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

//If you are passing product id
$stocks = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, array (905, 880)); //905 and 880 are my simple product ids

//If you are passing product sku
$stocks = $proxy->catalogInventoryStockItemList($sessionId, array ('sku1', 'sku2'));

print_r($stocks);

$proxy->endSession($sessionId);
```

For more details refer: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.list.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Below `code` for get all product stock list.

```
require_once('./app/Mage.php');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app(); 
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$skus = array();
foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
    $skus[] = $product->getSku();

}              
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourhost.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1');
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->catalogInventoryStockItemList($session, $skus);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>"; 
$client->endSession($session);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array(array("sku1","sku2","sku3"));
```

Yes, the nested arrays are necessary.  In mine I also had to append a blank space at the end of each sku, so it is actually:

```
 $products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array(array("sku1 ","sku2 ","sku3 "));
```

in my case.  Not sure why, just thrilled when I got it to work.

I have about a thousand products, but it seems to overload the server to put them all in one call, so I'm "chunking" the sku array like so:

```
foreach (array_chunk($sku_array, 100) as $skuChunk) {

    try {
        $products = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_stock.list', array($skuChunk));
    }
    catch (SoapFault $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
    }    
}
```